# How to fix it if your variables aren't passing

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I am using php and mysql.  Below is the code...  When I select the 'State', I should get a list of cities in that state...  However, it's not pulling any of the cities...  Looks like 'State' value is not pushed to query for cities...  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
</head>  

 <body>  
 <div id="wrapper">  

 <div id="header">  

 <h1>Tomorrow's Toys Today</h1>  
 </div>  
 <div id="subheader">  
 </div>  

 <div id="leftmenu">  

 <?php  

  include("misc.inc");                                           // 11


  $connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password)             // 13
       or die ("couldn't connect to server");
  $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection)                   // 15
       or die ("Couldn't select database");


$state=@$_GET['state'];   

$city=@$_GET['city'];  


 @$quer=mysql_query("SELECT state  FROM states");   


echo '************' , $state;

 if(isset($state) and strlen($state) > 0){  

 @$quer2=mysql_query("SELECT city FROM cities c, states s where c.state_id = s.state_id and s.state = $state ");   

 }else{$quer2=mysql_query("SELECT city FROM cities c, states s where c.state_id = s.state_id and s.state = $state"); };



 echo "<form method=post name=f1 action='dd-check.php'>";  
 echo "<table> <tr><td>";  



 echo "State";  

 echo"</td><td>";  

 echo "<select name='state' onchange=\"reload(this.form)  \"><option value=''>Select one</option>";  

 while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($quer)) {   

 if($noticia['state=']==$state){  

         echo "<option value='$noticia[state]'>$noticia[state]</option>"."<BR>";}  

     else{  

         echo  "<option value='$noticia[state]'>$noticia[state]</option><br>";}  

 }  

 echo "</select></td></tr><tr><td>";  


 echo "City";  

 echo "</td><td>";  

 echo "<select name='city' onchange=\"reload(this.form)  \"><option value=''>Select one</option>";  

 while($noticia2 = mysql_fetch_array($quer2)) {   

 if($noticia2['city=']==$city){  

         echo "<option value='$noticia2[city]'>$noticia2[city]</option>"."<BR>";}  

     else{  

         echo  "<option value='$noticia2[city]'>$noticia2[city]</option>";}  

 }  


 echo "</select></td></tr><tr><td>";  

 echo "<input type=submit value=Show></td></tr></table>";  
 echo "<input type=text name=state value=$state>";  
 echo "</form>";  
?>  


 </div>  

 <div id="main">  



 </div>  


 </div>
```

Comment: Don't suppress errors using `@`. That only makes it impossible to debug.

Answer (score 3):

Is $_GET['state'] a string? if so you should do something like this:

```
 $quer2=mysql_query("SELECT city FROM cities c, states s where c.state_id = s.state_id and s.state = '".mysql_real_escape_string($state)."'");
```

Strings need the quotes. Int do not. EIther way you should sanitize that input.

Also, there are much better ways at suppressing errors than using @ on everything...
http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: If is set, isn't $_GET['state'] always a string?

Comment: @JeffPigarelli the request super globals are always strings

Comment: Even if it is a literal string it will be interpreted as int if it is numeric ([0-9]+). I simply meant the difference between $_GET['state'] = 1 vs. $_GET['state'] = 'AZ'

Comment: Then you should copy my query above and pay specific attention to this line: '".mysql_real_escape_string($state)."' - you need the single quotes surrounding the variable and mysql_real_escape_string() help prevent you from being destroyed by even a novice hacker.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @$quer2=mysql_query("SELECT city FROM cities c, states s where c.state_id = s.state_id and s.state = $state ");   

}else{$quer2=mysql_query("SELECT city FROM cities c, states s where c.state_id = s.state_id and s.state = $state"); };
```

echo "$state"; will give you output $state
use echo $state; or echo "{$state}";

in your case

```
@$quer2=mysql_query("SELECT city FROM cities c, states s where c.state_id = s.state_id  and s.state = ".$state." ");   
}else{$quer2=mysql_query("SELECT city FROM cities c, states s where c.state_id = s.state_id and s.state = ".$state.""); };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers.. I tried:  echo "$state";
echo "{$state}";  Neither showed me the state..  I also tried the @query2 statement provided by Karol and Qing and neither is returning results!  Any other suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: After I select the state, I did a view source and am getting the following message.. how do I resolve it?  I'm new to PHP!  Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
</head>  

 <body>  
 <div id="wrapper">  

 <div id="header">  `enter code here`

 <h1>Tomorrow's Toys Today</h1>  
 </div>  
 <div id="subheader">  
 </div>  

 <div id="leftmenu">  

 <form method=post name=f1 action='dd-check.php'><table> <tr><td>State</td><td><select name='state' onchange="reload(this.form)  "><option value=''>Select one</option><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: state= in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Dummies\index.php</b> on line <b>62</b><br />
<option value='Virginia'>Virginia</option><BR><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: state= in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Dummies\index.php</b> on line <b>62</b><br />
<option value='Maryland'>Maryland</option><BR><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: state= in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Dummies\index.php</b> on line <b>62</b><br />
<option value='Washington DC'>Washington DC</option><BR><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: state= in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Dummies\index.php</b> on line <b>62</b><br />
<option value='Colorado'>Colorado</option><BR></select></td></tr><tr><td>City</td><td><select name='city' onchange="reload(this.form)  "><option value=''>Select two</option><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Dummies\index.php</b> on line <b>81</b><br />
</select></td></tr><tr><td><input type=submit value=Show></td></tr></table><input type=text name=state value=></form>
```